# How to enable all tests in NUnit source file in Visual Studio like how you run NUnit test in other projects?

Tags: c#, nunit

Sorry for troubling you guys again but help would be much appreciate.

I am interested in building and debugging NUnit source code. I would like to learn and contribute to the NUnit community.

I downloaded the source code from Github page [NUnit 3 Framework](https://github.com/nunit/nunit) to my computer and opened the nunit.sln solution file. I followed the instruction to build it and it built successfully.
the build console reported as

```
Done building project "nunit.framework.tests.csproj".

========== Build: 9 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

The problem is I want to view all the tests that are in the solution within visual studio test explorer. However when I open the test explorer, I don't see any tests.
In the test output window, this is the message I see.

```
========== Test discovery aborted: 0 Tests found in 7.5 sec ==========
No tests found to run.
```

I looked throught the source code and I can see classes with TestFixture attribute, and method with Test attribute, so I do know tests do exist within the solution. However they are not visible in VS test explorer.

The documentation only mention about the console runner and GUI runner, but I would like to use it in VS test explorer.

Also I installed the NUnit3TestAdapter and installed NUnit (but there was an error message, that all the files in the NUnit already present, so I uninstalled it.)

So my question is

- is there a way to enable all the tests to be visible inside VS test explorer?
- is there some configuration I need to do, to enable it.

I am really sorry in advance if I cause any trouble since I am quite new here, and thank you for everyone taking the time reading it and answering it.

Comment: You've told us a lot but left a few key things out. When you say "NUnit source" which project do you mean? For example, is it he NUnit framework? Or console? Or ...? Where did you get the source and how... there are various ways and you get different things depending on what you did. Did you clone the repository, for example? I assume you want to use VS Test Explorer. In that case, did you install the NUnit3 adapter into the project? (Please edit your question rather than adding comments.)

Comment: Thank you Charlie, will do what you recommended :)

Comment: What displays for you in the Test Explorer output window when you try to discover tests?